# Empty Spaces in Dash Graph: How to Remove Them?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I have created a graph in Dash using Plotly, and I'm encountering empty spaces at the top and right of the graph. You can see the graph here: [Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZN10.png).

**Question:**
Is it possible to remove these blank spaces and make the graph fit perfectly within its container?

**Code for graph:**

```
monte_carlo_graph = dcc.Graph(
            id="monte_carlo_graph",
            figure=go.Figure(
                data=simulations_traces,
                layout=go.Layout(
                    showlegend=False,
                    title="",
                    yaxis=dict(
                        autorange=True,
                        title="Price",
                        titlefont=dict(color="white"),
                        tickfont=dict(color="white"),
                        gridcolor="grey",
                    ),
                    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
                    xaxis=dict(
                        autorange=True,
                        title="Days",
                        titlefont=dict(color="white"),
                        tickfont=dict(color="white"),
                        gridcolor="grey",
                    ),
                    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                ),
            ),
            className="monte-carlo-graph",
        )
```

**Css styling for the graph:**

```
.monte-carlo-graph {
height: 600px;
width: 900px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #211F32;
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 0px !important;
padding-top: 0px !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
```

}

I have tried adjusting the height and width in the CSS, but it didn't solve the issue. How can I remove these empty spaces from the graph? Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I needed to add this line to my graph layout:

`margin=go.layout.Margin(r=0, t=0,),`

So the code looks like this now:

```
monte_carlo_graph = dcc.Graph(
            id="monte_carlo_graph",
            figure=go.Figure(
                data=simulations_traces,
                layout=go.Layout(
                    showlegend=False,
                    title="",
                    yaxis=dict(
                        autorange=True,
                        title="Price",
                        titlefont=dict(color="white"),
                        tickfont=dict(color="white"),
                        gridcolor="grey",
                    ),
                    margin=go.layout.Margin(r=0, t=0,),
                    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
                    xaxis=dict(
                        autorange=True,
                        title="Days",
                        titlefont=dict(color="white"),
                        tickfont=dict(color="white"),
                        gridcolor="grey",
                    ),
                    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                ),
            ),
            className="monte-carlo-graph",
        )
```

But I have another question, is it possible to do this by changing css styling in used className?